# How do I escape newline character in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to convert some xml files to a csv. Some tags contain descriptive text which has newlines. Obviously this throws off my csv. I'm thinking of replacing newlines, within tags, to some other character and change it back if I need to render the text.

Here is an example:

xml

```
<myxml>
 ...
 <description>
1. Do this
2. Do that
3. You are done
  </description>
...
</myxml>
```

How do I replace the newlines character in the `<description>` tag?

Edit:
Regarding newlines and csv standards, let's just say I want to remove newlines from text between a tag -- perhaps replace '\n' with `<br/>`. This is really an xslt, rather than a csv question.

Regarding which version of xslt, I'm using xsltproc on linux. Whichever version that supports.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1 or 2?  Also, CSV allows for newlines inside strings assuming the program reading the CSV is using a standard-compliant CSV parser.  You should probably verify that you actually need to do something about the embedded newlines.

Comment: CSV is not a standard, it is a set of loose conventions. The way to represent newlines within fields (if it's possible at all) is going to depend on what the receiving application will accept. Before we can answer the question, therefore, we need to know exactly what output you want to generate.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm using xsltproc on unix. Not sure which version it supports.

Comment: @MichaelKay I just want to run a `replace` command on text inside a pair of tags. It is very difficult to google this because I get all kinds of irrelevant results.

Comment: A `br` element does not make sense in a CSV document in my view. As for replacing parts of a string with XSLT 1 (as that is what xsltproc supports) like a newline character with an element, see http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/replace.html#d8770e19